# Azure App Insights how can sum of a metric go downwards when the values are always that are logged are always positive?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a metric that I'm tracking using TelemetryClient.TrackMetric and the values I'm reporting are always positive (time duration in seconds), yet the chart of my custom metric with "Summation" selected goes down hill.  How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share sample query & result you are getting.  Chart is based on data or result of the query.

Comment: Do you keep sending the metrics?

Answer (score 2):

The metrics in the Azure Portal are always displayed depending on a certain time granularity. So, for example, if you select the time range "last hour" and time granularity "5 minutes" you will get 12 data points displaying the sum (or any other selected aggreagtion) of whatever metric you have selected.
It does not aggregate the metrics for the complete time range, only per selected granularity.

[image]

The dotted line means that no data has arrived for these timestamps yet.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I can think of the sum function then as "sliding over that Time granularity window" ?

Comment: So is there another graph I can build that will give me a total over time?  I'm trying to look at adoption of a new tool and so total numbers are interesting, not just sliding windows...

Comment: Yes, the graph is showing the sum over the selected granularity. You can see the total of the sum in the lower left corner of your graph. However, only as a number, not as a graph. Not sure though why you would need the accumulated sum over the entire time range. I think this wouldn't be really significant and does not tell the user a lot. Maybe if you explain your exact use case we can find an appropriate solution.